# Valid value range(not query range) for date format in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the valid value range? For example, is it like Epoch Timestamp or we could add values like 1536-22-05?

### What have I tried so far?

Well it's not a matter of trying. I've just started to work with elasticsearch, and I'm working on my schema. For the date part, I was wondering if it would compare dates which were for hundreds of years ago, and no matter how much I searched I didn't find a straight answer. So I felt like there should be an answer to this question somewhere, thus I asked it here, just for the sake of having it somewhere.

To answer the above question I added the following values:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "pezeshkyab",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "mydate": "1369-05-09"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "pezeshkyab",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "mydate": "1379-05-09"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "pezeshkyab",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "mydate": "1990-05-09"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and then executed this query:

```
POST /pezeshkyab/test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "mydate": {
                "gt": "1359-01-01",
                "lt": "1399-12-12"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and got this:

```
{
   "took": 74,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "pezeshkyab",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "mydate": "1369-05-09"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "pezeshkyab",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "mydate": "1379-05-09"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

So the answer is pretty obvious, I just wanted to put the answer somewhere so that future searches by other people would yield some result.

Comment: What did you try and what failed?

Comment: @bittusarkar Checkout the edit. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that your "mydate" field is not being stored in ES as a date.

Here is a sample that explicitly sets "f2" as a date in ES, this will allow for proper querying/filtering.

```
PUT test

PUT /test/_mapping/type1
{
    "type1" : {
        "properties" : {
            "f1" : {"type" : "string"},
            "f2" : {"type" : "date"}
        }
    }
}

--verify the mapping
GET test/type1/_mapping

POST test/type1
{
  "f1": "record 1",
  "f2": "2000-01-01"
}

POST test/type1
{
  "f1": "record 2",
  "f2": "1500-01-01"
}

GET test/type1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "f2": {
            "gte": "1500-01-01",
            "lte": "1999-01-01"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this sample code "record 2" is correctly returned while "record 1" is excluded.

Comment: Well thanks for the answer but my code is working. I was just complaining that there's no mention of the date range anywhere. However your answer is pretty much helpful. The `1500-01-01` clarifies it.